Receiving an error `Before you change a matching rule, you must deactivate it`
Receiving an error while trying to update the matching rule
MatchingRule(Account.AccountMatchingRule) Before you change a matching rule, you must deactivate it., Details: Account.AccountMatchingRule:
Before you change a matching rule, you must deactivate it.


2) DuplicateRule An unexpected error occurred. Please include this ErrorId if you contact support: 381442211-479787 (651295128), Details:

Account.AccountDuplicateRule: An unexpected error occurred. Please include this ErrorId if you contact support: 381442211-479787 (651295128)

what are the options of resolving this?

To update those we need to delete metadata first
sf project delete source -r -m DuplicateRule:Account.AccountDuplicateRule 
sf project delete source -r -m MatchingRule:Account.AccountMatchingRule 

and then deploy the new version.
In case we have automated process which commit these files to Git, we also need to restore the files by executing commands
git checkout src/matchingRules/Account.matchingRule-meta.xml
git checkout src/duplicateRules/Account.AccountDuplicateRule.duplicateRule-meta.xml

